# Why does htmlentities return an empty string?

Tags: php

Why does htmlentities return an empty string:

```
<?php
session_start();
?>

    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

    <html>

    <head>
        <title>Index</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../stijlen.css" />
        <meta charset="UTF-8">

        <style>
        @charset "UTF-8"    

        </style>

    </head>

    <body>
        <h2>Main index</h2>


        <?php
            echo(htmlentities("José", ENT_NOQUOTES, "UTF-8"));
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

If I leave out the "UTF-8" part of the function it works fine. The "é" creates the problem, but I don't understand why. Why would this be an invalid character?

Comment: Could it be that your source file is NOT encoded in UTF8?

Comment: Is your complete file stored also in UTF-8 format? If you have an ISO file and you define UTF-8 in encoding than you have exactly this problem.

Comment: Edited: I did try to save the file as "UTF-8" but then I got an error message about session_start(); Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /home/st016/domains/domain.nl/public_html/portal/index.php:1) in /home/st016/domains/domain.nl/public_html/portal/index.php on line 2

Answer (score 5):

Your source file is not in UTF8. The [php documentation for `htmlentities()`](http://php.net/htmlentities) states that:

> If the input string contains an invalid code unit sequence within the given encoding an empty string will be returned, unless either the ENT_IGNORE or ENT_SUBSTITUTE flags are set.